# Mysql query issue with left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and trying to join both of them based on primary and foreign key.But the problem is that in second table the foreign key has duplicate rows.

1 Table - category

```
catid   catname
1       AAA
2       BBB
3       CCC
```

2 Table - answers

```
ansid    catid
1        1
2        1
3        2
4        2
```

The result should be

```
catid   catname   present in answers table
1       AAA       yes
2       BBB       yes
3       CCC       no
```

My query is

```
select * from category 
left join answers on category.catid=answers.catid
group by answers.catid
```

But it is not returning the results what I want.

Comment: Can you describe your desired output? What do you want to see? It just looks like the category table.

Comment: You want to categories that have the answers?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I have re edited my question

Comment: Actually I want catid, catname and a yes/no to determine if that cat id is present in answers table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select c.catid, 
       c.catname, 
       case when sum(a.catid is not null) > 0
            then 'no' 
            else 'yes' 
       end as present_in_answers_table
from category c
left join answers a on c.catid = a.catid
group by c.catid, c.catname
```

Comment: Awesome...brilliant.It worked like charm....now I need to understand this when clause.Thank you so much for saving my life.

Comment: You can sum up the records where the category is found in the answers table. With the `case` you can put a label on that condition

Comment: Got it now.Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below

```
select c.*,
case when a.ansid is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as `present in answers table`
from category c
left join answers a on c.catid = a.catid
```